# Examples and tutorials for TopLink

Tags: oracle, toplink

I can't find any good tutorials or examples of simple application that would map object to relational database using TopLink. Do you know any?

The only one, that I could find was: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/index-092145.html, but this is for old version of TopLink.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/b32441/toc.htm (for 11i).

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

TopLink 11 bundles EclipseLink for its implementation.

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples